# Search all dirs and subdirs in current dir for files that match list of file extensions. Copy those files to new dir maintaining file structure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file with a long list of file extensions:

```
.sln
.csproj
.cs
.xaml
.cshtml
.javasln
.project
.java
... (etc)
```

I have three project directories each with many subdirectories.

I can get a list of all the files and paths with: `find . -type f -printf "%p\n"`

```
./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/build/home.ini
./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/images/spring-pivotal-logo.png
./DirectoryB/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/data.sql
./DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project
```

I want to loop through those, and if the file extension matches one from my list, copy it to `myCopyDirectory` while maintaining their directory structure.

That is to say if `./DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project` file extension matches `.project` (as it does) as one of the extensions in my text file ... copy it to a new directory like `./myCopyDirectory` as: `./myCopyDirectory/DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project`.

So I will need a for or while loop, please forgive my awful pseudo code here but this is my vision

Scenario 1:  Copy files on the fly

```
for FILE in `find . -type f -printf "%p\n"`; do if [ ${FILE##*.} in extensions.txt ]; then mkdir -p ./myCopyDirectory/DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/ && cp ./DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project ./myCopyDirectory/DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project
```

Scenario 2:  Build a list of files that match and copy them

```
for FILE in `find . -type f -printf "%p\n"`; do if [ ${FILE##*.} in extensions.txt ]; then echo $FILE >> listOfFiles.txt

for FILE in `cat listOfFiles.txt`; do filename="${FILE##*/}" && dir="${FILE:0:${#FILE} - ${#filename}}" && if [ -e ./myCopyDirectory/$dir ]; then mkdir -p ./myCopyDirectory/$dir && cp $FILE ./myCopyDirectory
```

Scenario 3: Just `cp -R` all three dirs to `./myCopyDirectory` and rip out all files that do not match the extensions in the extensions.txt file

Please excuse my awful pseudo code.  I am just trying to make this work and am a bit out of my depth.  I could create a PERL or Python script to do it but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Fix the problems in your script described at [why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice), http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082, and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix anything extra it tells you about and then let us know if you still have a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need a for loop; in fact, you can take advantage of `find`'s `-exec` option to pass even a complex shell command to it to handle the "directory-preserving" copy procedure.

The following one-liner should work (explanation below).

```
find root1 -regex '.*\.\(ext1\|ext2\)$' -exec sh -c 'dir=${1%/*}; dir=${dir/root1/root2}; file=${1##*/}; mkdir -p $dir && cp $1 $dir/$file' _ {} \;
```

I have tested it by creating the following example directory tree,

```
$ mkdir root1
$ mkdir root1/sub
$ mkdir root1/sub/dir
$ touch root1/a.ext1 root1/a.ext2 root1/a.ext3 root1/sub/a.ext1 root1/sub/a.ext2 root1/sub/a.ext3 root1/sub/dir/a.ext1 root1/sub/dir/a.ext2 root1/sub/dir/a.ext3
$ tree root1/
root1/
├── a.ext1
├── a.ext2
├── a.ext3
└── sub
    ├── a.ext1
    ├── a.ext2
    ├── a.ext3
    └── dir
        ├── a.ext1
        ├── a.ext2
        └── a.ext3

2 directories, 9 files
```

and then executing the command on it and inspecting the result

```
$ find root1 -regex '.*\.\(ext1\|ext2\)$' -exec sh -c 'dir=${1%/*}; dir=${dir/root1/root2}; file=${1##*/}; mkdir -p $dir && cp $1 $dir/$file' _ {} \;
$ tree root2
root2
├── a.ext1
├── a.ext2
└── sub
    ├── a.ext1
    ├── a.ext2
    └── dir
        ├── a.ext1
        └── a.ext2

2 directories, 6 files
```

- The `-regex` option is used to find files that have extension `ext1` or `ext2`;
- the `-exec` option is used to execute the following `sh`ell command on each file found;
- this command is passed the command string through the `-c` option, and then a dummy placeolder `_` for the parameter `0` and `{}`, which is the name of the file as found by `find`, for the parameter `1`;
- the shell command string

  - extracts the directory `dir` of each file by removing the last `/` and whatever follows it from `$1` (which has been passed `{}`),
  - then changes it by substituting `root2` for `root1`;
  - similarly, it extracts the filename `file`;
  - finally, it creates the new directory structure with `mkdir`, and copies the file in it.

I have not included the `-type f` option, but you can if you really have folders names with an extension equal to one of those you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `find` with a `while read loop` plus some shell features.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

##: If bash is lower that v4, one alternative is.
##: while read -r lines; do extensions+=("${lines#*.}"); done < file_with_extension.txt

##: This assumes that the file_with_extensions.txt is in the same
##: directory as the files/directory that you're going to process, 
##: change the correct path e.g. /path/to/file_with_extension.txt

mapfile -t extensions < file_with_extension.txt

##: Add as much directory you need.
Dirs=(
  ./DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/
  ./DirectoryB/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/
  ./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/images
  ./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/build
  /AnotherDirectory/From/another/Path
  /A/Not/So/distant/Directory/From/Far/Far/Away
  /One/Directory/To/Rule/Em/All
)

ext=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "*.@(${extensions[*]#*.})" )

dest=./myCopyDirectory

while IFS= read -d '' -r files ; do
  if [[ $files = $ext ]]; then
     echo mkdir -p "$dest/${files%/*}" && echo cp -v "${files}" "$dest/${files%/*}"
  fi
done < <(find "${Dirs[@]}" -type f -print0)
```

---

- Remove the `echo` if you think the output is correct.
- That should be safe from white-space,tabs and newlines in the file & path name, that's the only advantage from the other post on this question.
- The disadvantage? It requires `bash4+` because of `mapfile` (See the comment on the script for the work around) and it is not a `oneliner` :-)

---

A sample simulation.

```
mkdir -p /tmp/testing123 && cd /tmp/testing123
```

```
mkdir -p ./DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/
mkdir -p ./DirectoryB/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/
mkdir -p ./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/images
mkdir -p ./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/build/
```

```
touch ./DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project
touch ./DirectoryB/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/data.sql
touch ./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/images/spring-pivotal-logo.png
touch ./DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/build/home.ini
```

Make sure both the `script` above and the `files_with_extensions.txt` is in the same directory as your current pwd/cwd.

Run the script.

```
./myscript
```

Output

```
'DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/images/spring-pivotal-logo.png' -> './myCopyDirectory/DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/images/spring-pivotal-logo.png'
'DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/build/home.ini' -> './myCopyDirectory/DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/build/home.ini'
'DirectoryB/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/data.sql' -> './myCopyDirectory/DirectoryB/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/data.sql'
'DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project' -> './myCopyDirectory/DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project'
```

Check the directory/files of `myCopyDirectory`

```
find myCopyDirectory/ -type f
```

Output

```
myCopyDirectory/DirectoryC/src/main/resources/project/schema.project
myCopyDirectory/DirectoryB/src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/data.sql
myCopyDirectory/DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/images/spring-pivotal-logo.png
myCopyDirectory/DirectoryA/src/main/resources/static/resources/build/home.ini
```

---

Let's break it down.

- `shopt -s extglob` Enable the shell feature so the test in `[[ ]]` will work.
- `mapfile -t extensions < file_with_extension.txt` Saves the file extensions from the file to an array named `extensions`
- `ext=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "*.@(${extensions[*]#*.})" )` Format the array named `extension` using the value of `IFS` in a structure `extglob` understand inside the `[[ ]]` test. The `#*.` removes the leading `.` dot from each element/entry from the array.
- `dest=./myCopyDirectory` Saves the leading directory structure in the variable named `dest`
- `while IFS= read -d '' -r files` By default `read` strips leading and trailing white spaces, so `IFS=` (which is the default value) is needed to disable that feature. `-d ''` is safe from `null` delimited input, `-r` is safe from input that has back slashes.
- `[[ $files = $ext ]]` If the files from `find` matches the extension from the lists that was converted in an array and was converted into a format that `extglob` understands.
- `mkdir -p "$dest/${files%/*}"` Create the leading directory structure plus the directory structure of the matched file. The `-p` saves you a lot of trouble and errors, see `mkdir --help` or `info mkdir` or `man mkdir`
- `cp -v "${files}" "$dest/${files%/*}"` Copy (`-v` is verbose) the matched file into the new created directory with the desired structure. The `${files%/*}` strips the trailing `/` from the output of find and since a `/` is not allowed to be in a `file name` ( at least with the file systems that I'm using) It is guaranteed that you're just removing the path from the file name.
- `< <(find "${Dir[@]}" -type f -print0)` the `<()` Is called Process Substitution. `"${Dirs[@]}"` will expand to ALL the elements since it is an array. `-type f` Will make sure that you're only interested in normal files and not directories and so on. `-print0` Outputs a `null` delimited structure.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well.  My thanks to all who helped.  Please, improvements and suggestions welcome!  Thanks again.

```
find ./myDirToSearch -type f -regex ".*\.\(sln\|csproj\|cs\|xaml\|cshtml\|javasln\|project\|java\)" -exec cp --parents \{\} ./myCopyDir \;
```

Comment: Why `\{\}` and not a nicer `'{}'`? I did not know of `--parents`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and find):

```
find . -type f |
parallel --rpl '{d} s:.*?/::;s:/[^/]*$::' \
  'mkdir -p myCopyDirectory/{1d} && \
   [ {1} = {1.}{2} ] && \
   cp -v {1} myCopyDirectory/{1d}/{1/}' :::: - :::: ../fileExts.txt
```

Use the find command to print out only files within/under the current directory.

Pipe the resulting file strings into  the parallel command as parameter 1.

Define a replacement string in parallel called `{d}` this strips the top directory and the file name from the input string.

Make a directory in the current one using the above strings (use the `-p` option to force the intermediate directories to be created).

Test the current file against the required file extensions as parameter 2 (keep those extensions in a text file in the directory above this current one or where ever).

If the extensions match, cp the current file into the created backup using the verbose option so as to see the files that are copied (this may be removed for a silent run).

For testing purposes, use the `--dryrun` option in parallel to see the commands generated and once approved the option can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This solution reads the file extensions for the `find` command from the file: "./extensions.txt".

```
mapfile -t < ./extensions.txt; exts=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "${MAPFILE[*]#*.}" ); exts=`echo $exts | sed 's/|/\\\|/'`; find ./myDirToSearch -type f -regex ".*\.\($exts\)" -exec cp --parents {} ./myCopyDir \;
```

Same, but separated into multiple lines to make it easier to read:

```
mapfile -t < ./extensions.txt; \
exts=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "${MAPFILE[*]#*.}" ); \
exts=`echo $exts | sed 's/|/\\\|/'`; \
find ./myDirToSearch -type f -regex ".*\.\($exts\)" -exec cp --parents {} ./myCopyDir \;
```

Or awk may be used instead of bash to set "exts":

```
exts=`awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } \
    { exts[NR] = $2 } \
    END { i = 0; \
        for (key in exts) { \
            printf "%s", exts[key]; \
            if (++i != NR) { printf "\\\|" } \
         } \
         printf "\n" \
    }' ./extensions.txt`; \
find ./myDirToSearch -type f -regex ".*\.\($exts\)" -exec cp --parents {} ./myCopyDir \;
```

Or for those on us on a Mac (note the `-E` option for `find` and the removing of escaped chars in the regex and `exts` bash variable):

```
exts=`awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." } { exts[NR] = $2 } END { i = 0; for (key in exts) { printf "%s", exts[key]; if (++i != NR) { printf "|" } } printf "\n" }' ./extensions.txt`; find -E ./myDirToSearch -type f -regex ".*\.($exts)" -exec bash -c 'dir=`dirname {}`; dir=./myCopyDir/$dir; mkdir -p $dir; cp {} $dir' \;
```